# How to Connect 2 SQL queries with unequal column and rows

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I want to join these 2 queries and show the result as below in picture. How can i do it. I am a student using Oracle-Apex.

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    Room_Dim.BandDesc, TO_CHAR(BookedStartDate, 'Month') AS Month,     
    COUNT(Fact_Bookings_Payments.RoomID) AS Reserved 
FROM 
    Room_Dim, Fact_Bookings_Payments
WHERE 
    Room_Dim.RoomID = Fact_Bookings_Payments.RoomID 
GROUP BY 
    Room_Dim.BandDesc, TO_CHAR(BookedStartDate, 'Month')
ORDER BY 
    Room_Dim.BandDesc, TO_CHAR(BookedStartDate, 'Month') DESC;
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    Room_Dim.BandDesc, COUNT(Room_Dim.RoomID) AS TotalRooms
FROM 
    Room_Dim
GROUP BY 
    Room_Dim.BandDesc
ORDER BY 
    Room_Dim.BandDesc;
```

[enter image description here][image: 1]

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use join to have your desired result. If you want to select rows only if BandDesc exist in both the queries then inner join will do the trick.

```
select t.BandDesc,Month, Reserved, TotalRooms from

(SELECT Room_Dim.BandDesc, to_char(BookedStartDate, 'Month') AS Month,     COUNT(Fact_Bookings_Payments.RoomID)AS Reserved 
FROM Room_Dim, Fact_Bookings_Payments
WHERE Room_Dim.RoomID = Fact_Bookings_Payments.RoomID 
GROUP BY Room_Dim.BandDesc, to_char(BookedStartDate, 'Month'))t

inner join 

(SELECT Room_Dim.BandDesc, COUNT(Room_Dim.RoomID) AS TotalRooms
FROM Room_Dim
GROUP BY Room_Dim.BandDesc)t2

on t.BandDesc=t2.BandDesc       
ORDER BY BandDesc, Month DESC
```

If you want to join three tables then that will be something like this:

```
select ... from t
inner join t2     on t.BandDesc=t2.BandDesc       
inner join t3     on t.BandDesc=t3.BandDesc       
ORDER BY BandDesc, Month DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much for immediate reply. I tried this, but didn't work. It gives me error : ORA-00904: "BOOKEDSTARTDATE": invalid identifier

Comment: @Sharma my mistake. There was error in order by clause. I have fixed that. Please try now.

Comment: error: ORA-00904: "T1"."BANDDESC": invalid identifier

Comment: Another mistake. But resolved. Since I don't have the data can't execute the query. Please check now.

Comment: Yes, it worked!! thank you so much!!!! You are awesome.

Comment: You are most welcome. Sorry for the early mistakes. Best wishes.\

Comment: Is it possible to have a chat with you? I actually need a little more help and i don't know the query for that. i would really appreciate if there can be way for us to chat and you can give your valuable time. and its kind a urgent. possible right now?

Comment: Will try my level best. What's your problem?

Comment: If i want to make another inner join to this (Lets Say t3), so what will be in the  ON statement ? t.BandDesc = t2.BandDesc = t3.BandDesc ????

Comment: after on clause and before order by you will insert another join like inner join t3 on t.BandDesc=t3.BandDesc

Comment: I tried it and it worked but my result are now limited by "Unavailable". Means, the rows reduced to where rooms are unavailable and am not able to get all data which i got in previous answer.                                                                                                           Inner join

(SELECT Room_Dim.BandDesc, COUNT(Room_Dim.RoomID) AS Unavailable 
FROM Room_Dim
WHERE AdditionalNotes = 'Unavailable'
GROUP BY Room_Dim.BandDesc)t3

on t.BandDesc=t3.BandDesc

Comment: Then please use Left join t3 instead of inner join. It will have all the rows from previous query and matching rows from t3.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you so much for your support! I must say that I got help from many people but,  you simplified the answer for a beginner!  Thank you so much. Best Wishes!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest phrasing the query as:

```
SELECT r.BandDesc, trunc(bp.BookedStartDate, 'Month') AS Month,     
       COUNT(bp.RoomID) AS Reserved,
       r.total_rooms
FROM (SELECT r.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY r.BandDesc) as total_rooms
      FROM Room_Dim r
     ) r LEFT JOIN
     Fact_Bookings_Payments bp
     ON r.RoomID = pb.RoomID 
GROUP BY r.BandDesc, trunc(bp.BookedStartDate, 'Month'), rd.total_rooms
ORDER BY r.BandDesc, trunc(bp.BookedStartDate, 'Month') DESC;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that bands with no reservations are included in the results.
- I replaced `to_char()` with `trunc()`.  The major differences is that `trunc()` includes the year -- and you really should be including years if you are looking at months, unless you very intentionally want to count the same month in different years.
- The `COUNT(*) OVER` counts the rooms with the same band.

Comment: Thank for your reply. This is my first attempt in SQL, really new to this. I copy pasted your code and got this error:  ORA-00904: "FB"."ROOMID": invalid identifier